# Do we say "in a state of..." or "in the state of..."?

Tags: phrase-choice

I wrote this sentence:

> John is in **the** state of limerence after he meets Jane.

My friend corrected me with:

> ... in **a** state of limerence ....

I am confused; I use the article "the" because it is a specific emotion.

What do you in the Forum think?

Answer (score 1):

> I am confused; I use the article "the" because it is a specific emotion.

But you're not referring to a unique emotion - you're referring to a *state* of emotion that a person is in, of which there could be many. For example, a person may experience a state of panic on multiple occasions, or they may experience various different emotional states at different times. These are clearly countable, so the indefinite article is correct.

Further, emotions are *abstract*, so when referring to them uniquely you wouldn't use an article at all. For example, you would talk about 'fear' with zero article (eg "*we all experience fear sometimes*"). However, we do use an article when referring to a specific *type* of fear - for example "*the fear of dogs*" if speaking about it in general, and "*a fear of dogs*" when speaking about a particular person's fear.

Comment: "The fear of dogs" if speaking about it in general?? How about just: Fear of dogs can be difficult to overcome. BUT: The fear of dogs he felt was not new.

Answer (score 0):

*In **a** state of…* is an idiomatic collocation. As, by the way, is the simple *in a state*. This latter can be heard as shorthand for *in a state of disorder*, or *distress*, or some other unfortunate condition.